# ASP.NET MVC 5 Form Post Reloads Page without Processing Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a form with about 50 fields using a combination of default and DevExpress Editors. I also am using knockout to bind textbox values to spans for calculations. The page renders fine but when I try to post to save the updates the controller's post action does not get hit and the page reloads with the old values visible.

I can't post the exact page but I can post snip-its.

Index.cshtml:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <b>Comapny:</b> @Html.Partial("_CompanyComboBox", Model)
    <br />
    @Html.Partial("_CompanyEditor", Model)
}
```

CompanyMonitoringController.cs:

```
[Route("CompanyMonitoring/{companyID:int?}")]
public ActionResult Index(int? companyID = null)
{
    var companies = this.CompanyRepository.GetCompanies().OrderBy(c => c.CoShtName);
    Company selectedComapny = companyID != null ? companies.Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID).Single() : companies.First();
    CompanyModel model = new CompanyModel(this.CompanyRepository.GetCompany(selectedComapny.CompanyID));
    PopulateLists(model, companies);
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))]CompanyModel model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        this.CompanyRepository.SaveCompany(model.ToCompany());
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { companyID = model.CompanyID });
      }
      PopulateLists(model);
      return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my co-workers answered the question.

1. Add `[HttpGet]` to the Index get method
2. Add `[Route("CompanyMonitoring/{companyID:int?}")]]` to the Index post method.

Comment: The `[HttpGet]` is not necessary, but the route on the post action method is for sure if you want to use the same URL for Get & Post.